# Partition problem

Tags: algorithms

While doing some programming, I found that I needed to design or implement an algortihm to basically do the same as the [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem),that consists in partitioning a set of integers in two groups with the most equitative sum, but with floating point numbers. Is there any "efficient" solution? I know it is NP-hard, but I at least would like a "not-so-exponential" algorithm. Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the best answer depends on the parameters of the problem. It is only nasty-nasty-nasty exponential if the numbers get large - large as in n bits for a large value of n, not large as in the number itself is large. For instance, if you had a thousand files that were all less than 10 megabytes in size and you wanted (for some reason) to put them on two DVDs and you wanted both DVDs to have the exact same amount of file space used, THAT could be solved very quickly. It would only take billions of billions of years if you threw out the constraint that they were all less than 10 megabytes in size and had the sizes capable of being things like 10^100 megabytes. This is the difference between strongly exponential and just exponential - because 10^100 is only a 100-digit number you see, and only takes 300ish bits to express.

One thing you could do - is use the fourier transform, and the property that convolution in time domain is equivalent to multiplication in frequency domain. So the dual possibilities that an element is in one set of the partition or the other, means it is either added or subtracted. So basically, if your numbers are 3, 7, 37, 22, and 101, you would have a function which is an impulse at 3 and -3, and another function which is an impulse at 7 and -7, etc., and then you convolve them all together; and by that I mean, you take the fourier transform, you multiply them, and then you just take the average of that function - if it is 0, then there is a frequency-0 component of 0, meaning there is no solution. And if it is nonzero, then there is a solution.

If however you do have some fairly large numbers (numbers like 10^100 taking 300 bits, not numbers like 10^300000 taking a megabyte), and you weren't concerned with getting an EXACT solution but just wanted to see if there was a NEAR solution, you could do the same concept - except just divide all the numbers by a power of 2 and round to the nearest integer, or perhaps round up AND down and have impulses at both integers, perhaps have the one it is closer to be an appropriately larger impulse. Then you wouldn't be doing a fourier transform on an unruly large quantity of points.

Comment: I will give a look at those. At this point and how I see the things i would be happy enough just to know if there exists an approximate solution to my dataset.Thanks in advance

Comment: Deleted comment, the additional text you wrote didnt appeared to me then.Thank you for your interest and attention